# F# Xamarin Android, extension methods with [<Extension>] attribute don't work

Tags: .net, xamarin, f#, xamarin.android

I'm using FSharp.Data.dll for dealing with json data. Also, I extensively use 'FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions' which includes calls to 'AsArray()', 'AsFloat()', 'AsString()'.

The problem is that I can't use them in F# Xamarin Android project. It always the following
[image]
[image]

I have all required references and I use `open FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions` in my script file. Also, when I type `.AsString()` VS15 correctly recognizes that this call exists and doesn't show any errors. It's only when I actually compile the project the problem pops up.

After countless attempts to figure out what's wrong I've found out that these calls are marked with `[<Extension>]` attribute in order to be compatible with C# extensions. After such revelations I quickly wrote some extension methods with `[<Extension>]` attribute and tried to apply it. And it failed again during build phase with compile-time errors afterwards.

I assume that the problem may be with runtime version of F# but I can't prove it  because versioning in F# is pretty horrendous and I'm not quite comfortable enough with F# yet. [image]

So the problem basically realated to the fact that extension methods with `[<Extension>]` attribute don't work in Xamarin. Is there any chance to fix it?

**PS** I definitely know that this code is working because I have a duplicate project (ordinary F# .NET console application) where I test new libraries and I have no problems whatsoever.

Comment: Do you have the extension attribute on the assembly, too?

Comment: @ReedCopsey sorry, but what do you mean by that? [<Extension>] attribute resides in 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices'